# Parse nested json tree using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a json nested tree that looks like this :

```
{
    "children": [
        {
            "children": [],
            "id": 9,
            "level": 1,
            "name": "Zone d'audit Interne"
        },
        {
            "children": [],
            "id": 10,
            "level": 1,
            "name": "Magasin PF"
        },
        {
            "children": [],
            "id": 11,
            "level": 1,
            "name": "Magasin MP"
        },
        {
            "children": [
                {
                    "children": [],
                    "id": 14,
                    "level": 2,
                    "name": "Packaging"
                },
                {
                    "children": [],
                    "id": 15,
                    "level": 2,
                    "name": "Labelling"
                },
                {
                    "children": [],
                    "id": 16,
                    "level": 2,
                    "name": "Assemblage Acc"
                }
            ],
            "id": 12,
            "level": 1,
            "name": " U4: Assembalge Finale"
        },
        {
            "children": [
                {
                    "children": [],
                    "id": 18,
                    "level": 2,
                    "name": "Contrôle traitement"
                },
                {
                    "children": [],
                    "id": 19,
                    "level": 2,
                    "name": "Tunnel de Séchage"
                },
                {
                    "children": [],
                    "id": 20,
                    "level": 2,
                    "name": "Traitement Mécanique"
                }
            ],
            "id": 17,
            "level": 1,
            "name": "U3: Traitement"
        },
        {
            "children": [
                {
                    "children": [],
                    "id": 23,
                    "level": 2,
                    "name": "Ass_Ligne 2"
                },
                {
                    "children": [],
                    "id": 24,
                    "level": 2,
                    "name": "Ass_ligne 1"
                },
                {
                    "children": [],
                    "id": 39,
                    "level": 2,
                    "name": "BU"
                }
            ],
            "id": 21,
            "level": 1,
            "name": "U2: Assemblage SF"
        },
        {
            "children": [
                {
                    "children": [],
                    "id": 26,
                    "level": 2,
                    "name": "Mgasin Tampon"
                },
                {
                    "children": [],
                    "id": 27,
                    "level": 2,
                    "name": "Contrôle Kitting"
                }
            ],
            "id": 25,
            "level": 1,
            "name": "U1: Kitting"
        },
        {
            "children": [],
            "id": 35,
            "level": 1,
            "name": "to-delete"
        }
    ],
    "id": 8,
    "level": 0,
    "name": "DEMO"
}
```

I've tried parsing it but I only figured out how to parse the first level.
I want to be able to parse it and print / use every node's level .
if possible I want to turn it into a list of objects so I can use it in my widgets,
If anyone  can help I'd be grateful

here's how am parsing it :

```
 Future<Map<String, dynamic>?> fetchPerimeterTree(
      {required int id, required String baseUrl}) async {
    try {
      final request = http.Request(
          'GET', Uri.parse("$baseUrl${Endpoints.fetchPerim}$id/json"));

      http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        debugPrint("Perimeters tree fetched with success");

        var jsonData = jsonDecode(await response.stream.bytesToString());

        List<dynamic> fetchData2 = jsonData["children"];

        fetchData2.forEach((element) {
          print(element["name"]);
          print(element["children"]);
          print(element["level"]);
        });
        print(fetchData2);

        return jsonData;
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to load perimeter tree ${response.statusCode}');
      }
    } catch (ex) {
      debugPrint(ex.toString());
    }
  }
```

Comment: could you show what have you tried so far? your code implementation?

Comment: could you include you class model and the way you are parse it?

Comment: I just added the method am using to parse the tree

Comment: your response only have two level children list?

Comment: @eamirho3ein no in this case it's just two , but it can be more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumed your json called `jsonData`, and define a class model like this:

```
class ChildModel {
  final int id;
  final int level;
  final String name;
  final List<ChildModel>? children;

  ChildModel(
      {required this.id,
      required this.level,
      required this.name,
      this.children});

  static ChildModel fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    List children = json["children"] as List;
    return ChildModel(
        id: json["id"],
        level: json["level"],
        name: json["name"],
        children: children.isNotEmpty
            ? children.map((e) => ChildModel.fromJson(e)).toList()
            : []);
  }
}
```

then you can get your data like this:

```
ChildModel result = ChildModel.fromJson(jsonData);
```

and you can test it like this:

```
print(" name = ${result.children?[3].children?[0].name}"); // name = Packaging
```

In this way you can cache all the layers of children.